# Error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am trying to display two datetimepickers but i'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function" . 
I've installed :

Install-Package Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker

Install-Package Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS

Here is the code :

```
@model MVCGreenhouseMonitoring.Models.Plotting.PlottingCalendarDropDownList
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />

</head>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#txtdatepicker1").datetimepicker();
        $("#txtdatepicker2").datetimepicker();
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("IntervalReports", "Greenhouse", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    Start Date: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDateCalendar, new { @id = "txtdatepicker1", @style = "width:200px;" })
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    End Date: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDateCalendar, new { @id = "txtdatepicker2", @style = "width:200px;" })
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
}
```

I have all the necessary scripts in the Scripts folder.

Comment: jquery.js not included before jquery-ui.js

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

Comment: Still the same problem even though i included jquery.js

Comment: @Maria were you ever able to resolve this?  I ran into this same issue, and it turns out I was including jQuery twice.  Removing the second reference solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Just include this on top of the other js files:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

And wrap your script like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery("#txtdatepicker1").datetimepicker();
        jQuery("#txtdatepicker2").datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: FYI the current way the OP has wrapped their scripts is simply a shorthand of the one you have suggested.

Comment: `$` causes name-conflict between jQuery and plain js hence why you have to call it differently.

Comment: For the OP's issue, the above approach is cleaner than `$.noConflict();`

Comment: Right I see, is this because one of the other libraries is also using `$` variable?

Comment: I'm not very sure. It could be another library or vanilla js.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you included the right path of jquery script and must be the first in the head tag of the html you can get the latest jquery script here https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the jQuery library before you can use jQuery UI n your page.

[How to use jQuery UI](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/)

Like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did that , but i still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery UI is dependant on the jQuery library.**

> jQuery UI is a widget and interaction library built on top of the
>   jQuery JavaScript Library that you can use to build highly interactive
>   web applications.

*https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/*

Make sure you include a reference to it before jQuery UI:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    -- jQuery.js reference here --
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did that , but i still have the same problem