# Bootstrap Popover not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have a popover set up that is not initialing. My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="xyz">...</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

I've included everything I need to CSS and library wise and managed to replicate the issue here in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/W3R3W0LF666/33rmse7m/

So far I've tried moved the initialization text to various places in the JS file to rule out any hierarchy issues

Comment: where have you included the js files on that jsfiddle? you have an error `TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function` the js lib isnt included in that fiddle

Comment: You forgot to include the `CSS` and `JS` of bootstrap, in your fiddle. Maybe same thing in your code ? Working : https://jsfiddle.net/33rmse7m/2/

Comment: That fixes the fiddle but still not fixed in my code - in my code the popover is inside a table - would that make a difference?

Comment: @LianeStevenson Can you share your live url, if available? Are you sure you've all the necessary files loaded properly ? It's working on fiddle though. https://jsfiddle.net/tusharkhatiwada/33rmse7m/3/

Comment: Is the table created / added during runtime?

Comment: It is yeah - it's bootstrap table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
```

Pop it

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code, Check code below [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33rmse7m/5/) :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
         placement : 'bottom'
    });
});

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button data-toggle="popover" class="btn btn-primary" data-content="xyz">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one this will help you..

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />


    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="XYZ">Toggle popover</a>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load the external resources.

From the docs:

> How popover is triggered - click | hover | focus | manual. You may
>   pass multiple triggers; separate them with a space. manual cannot be
>   combined with any other trigger.

You need to define the trigger `data-trigger="hover"`:

```
<div data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="xyz">...</div>
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojh0qL6u/1/).

PS: Yours actually works, but it only triggers on-click.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrapped your jQuery script like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

Or if you want to load the script on `document ready`, then use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

**Reason:** **`$`** causes name-conflict between **`jQuery`** and **`plain-js/other-libraries`** hence why you have to call it differently so the browser knows that jQuery and not some other library is using it.

Here's a jsfiddle with above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/33rmse7m/7/

Comment: This is not really his problem. It works even without the [wrapper](https://jsfiddle.net/37p0562f/1/).

Comment: @LeftyX On jsFiddle, it will work without the wrapper but on browser, he needs to add that wrapper.

This guy had the same issue as him: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962361/error-uncaught-typeerror-datetimepicker-is-not-a-function/31962549#31962549

Comment: And so is this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document